# How to add / edit / delete an element in both the database and the listbox properly using a BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm currently coding a WinForm application with a MS SQL database in background. I made a ListBox diplaying all the rows of a table from my database using a BindingSource with Linq-To-SQL and I do not understand how I can delete a record from the table and automatically update the ListBox. Is it not the interest of the BindingSource, to report changes to the data ?

I'm just looking for advice, not a ready-made solution ;-)

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no live connection between the database and the application.  The `BindingSource` is a link between the in-memory data cache and the UI.  It knows nothing about the database.  LINQ to SQL works by pulling data into the application from the database.  The application has to initiate the request.  The database doesn't push changes to the application because it has no idea what applications there are that may be using that data.  There might be a single instance of a single application or hundreds of users of multiple applications.

Comment: Thanks you, it's very helpful. But how can I do it properly ? Currently, in the case of deleting, I'm using DeleteOnSubmit and SubmitChanges for the database and RemoveAt on the BindingSource for updating the ListBox. Is that correct ?